# training a new model using pascal kit

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, pascal, object-detection

need some help on this.

Currently I am doing a project on computer vision that requires me to train a new model to detect a certain object.

In this case, I am using the system provided by P. Felzenszwalb, D. McAllester, D. Ramaman and his team => Discriminatively trained deformable part models which is implemented in Matlab.

Project webpage: http://www.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/latent/.

However I have no idea how to direct the system to use my dataset(a collection of images and annotation) which is different from the the PASCAL datasets so as to train a new model.

By directing, I meant a line of code that allows me to change the dataset the system reads from, for training a model.

E.g.

% directory for caching models, intermediate data, and results

cachedir = ['/var/tmp/rbg/YOURPATH/' VOCyear '/'];

I tried looking at their Readme and documentation guides but they do not make any mention. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Let me know if I have not made my problem clear enough.

I tried looking at some files such as global.m but no go.

Your help is much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: If they do not accept an input arguement, and you do not have acces to the source code, I would recommend this workaround: Find where their db is located and put your db in exactly that spot with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read pascal.m in the DPM package(voc-release5), there are similar code working on VOC2007/2010 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of parts that need to be adapted to achieve this. For example the voc_config has to be adapted in order to read from your files.

The same with the pascal_train.m function. Depending on the images and the way you parse them, this may require quite some time to adapt this function.

Other functions to consider:

- imreadx
- pascal_test
- pascaleval